# Уменьшение значения сессии

Tags: php, сессия

Почему, после того, как будет совпадение, то значение сессии, минусуется только 1 раз?

```
<?php error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; char set=utf-8');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

session_start();

$p1 = $_SESSION['player1'] = 10; //человек
$comp = $_SESSION['computer'] = 10; //комп

echo '$_SESSION["player1"] = ' .  $p1 . '<br>';

if(isset($_GET['num'])){
    if($_GET['num'] == rand(1, 3)){
        $p1--;
        echo 'Совпало ' . $p1;
    }   
    else{
        echo 'Не совпало';
    }
}


?>

<form action="" method="get">
    Введите число от 1 до 3 <input type="number" name="num">
    <input type="submit" name="Отправить">
</form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В смысле почему? Скрипт запускается один раз. Ты нажимаешь кнопку Отправить. Он запускается один раз. И у тебя написано, что если значения совпадают, то нужно отнять единицу один раз. Что вы ожидали вообще? Кроме того скрипт запускается каждый раз с самого начала. И всегда в начале будет 10.

И это можно объединить

```
if(isset($_GET['num']) and $_GET['num'] == rand(1, 3)){
    $p1--;
    echo 'Совпало ' . $p1; 
} else {
    echo 'Не совпало';
}
```

Самое простое - в начале проверить - существует ли сессия? Если нет, то записываем 10. Иначе не записываем, а берём то, что есть, пока не станет меньше нуля. Если меньше нуля, то начинаем всё с самого начала.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['player1'])) {
    $_SESSION['player1']=10;
    $p1=$_SESSION['player1'];
} elseif ($_SESSION['player1']<0) {
    echo ('Меньшя нуля');
    unset($_SESSION['player1']); //удалем
}
```

В итоге:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; char set=utf-8');
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['player1'])) {
        $_SESSION['player1']=10;
    } elseif ($_SESSION['player1']<0) {
        echo ('Меньшя нуля');
        unset($_SESSION['player1']); //удалем
    }

    echo '$_SESSION["player1"] = '.$_SESSION['player1'].'<br>';

    if(isset($_GET['num']) and $_GET['num'] == rand(1, 3)){
        $_SESSION['player1']--;
        echo 'Совпало '.$_SESSION['player1']; 
    } else {
        echo 'Не совпало';
    }
?>

<form action="" method="get" name='formrand'>
    <label>Введите число от 1 до 3 <input type="number" name="num" value='1'></label>
    <input type="submit" name="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: А как сделать, что бы значение 10 не перезаписывалось?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что каждый раз в сессию перезаписываются значения `player1` и `computer` в значение `10`, а далее изменяется не значение сессии, а значение переменной. Должно работать вот так:

```php
<?php error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; char set=utf-8');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

session_start();

$_SESSION['player1'] = isset($_SESSION['player1']) ? $_SESSION['player1'] : 10; //человек
$_SESSION['computer'] = isset($_SESSION['computer']) ? $_SESSION['computer']: 10; //комп

echo '$_SESSION["player1"] = ' .  $_SESSION['player1'] . '<br>';

if(isset($_GET['num'])){
    if($_GET['num'] == rand(1, 3)){
        $_SESSION['player1']--;
        echo 'Совпало ' . $_SESSION['player1'];
    }   
    else{
        echo 'Не совпало';
    }
}


?>

<form action="" method="get">
    Введите число от 1 до 3 <input type="number" name="num">
    <input type="submit" name="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: А как сделать, что бы значение 10 не перезаписывалось?

Comment: мне надо, что бы изначально было 10, а ваш код выдаёт сразу 1

Comment: Ошибся, исправил ответ

Comment: всё равно 1 остался

Comment: Потому что в сессии 1 записалось. Должно уменьшаться. Перед проверкой скрипта очистите сессию.